# How to check a file upload control in a custom validator

Tags: java, validation, xpages

I have created a custom validator in Java that I use on my XPage. All data are bound to a managed bean (including "child" data sets - rows - of the main data entity). In my validate method I check for the row component (and find some of its "siblings" to check that if one is filled the other also has to be filled or its value within a certain interval). This works fine for ordinary fields (selects, inputs, and checkboxes).

But how can I get a hold of the file upload control? A picture has to be attached if a checkbox in the same row is checked. This is the definition of my fileUpload:

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUploadSingle" value="#{row.photo}"
    disableClientSideValidation="true" required="true">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validator validatorId="fishingTripValidator"></xp:validator>
        <xp:validateRequired message="You must attach a photo"></xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:fileUpload>
```

I think there are two issues at hand:

1. How to trigger "required" serverside. I have tested this by just setting the field to required. Works fine client-side - but does not trigger server-side... However, my validate method IS called if a value is filled in (i.e. selected a file) and I can read the value into a com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile variable and get e.g. the client file name (getClientFileName()).
2. Get a hold of the file upload control when finding that the checkbox has been checked - and test if the file upload control has any file specified in it...

I can find the right control as a UIComponent and get a hold of the com.ibm.xsp.component.UIFileuploadEx.UploadedFile object. See this snippet:

```
com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspFileUpload fileUpload = (com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspFileUpload) component;
if (null != fileUpload) {
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIFileuploadEx.UploadedFile uploadedFile = (com.ibm.xsp.component.UIFileuploadEx.UploadedFile) fileUpload.getValue();
    if (null != uploadedFile) {
        return uploadedFile.getFilename();
    }
}
return null;
```

The strange thing is that when I check the box AND attach a file - the above code will NOT find the file - and the validator returns an error. The filename shown on the file upload control has now disappeared. However, if I save again without changing anything then the file control in the code snippet correctly now finds the file - so no validation error is thrown and the file is correctly uploaded...

If only I could trigger validation on "required" I think I could avoid the other "hacks" where obviously something is happening "in between" the two save's.

Any ideas to how I can control this correctly??

/John

Comment: You need to put the validator into the upload control. There you can use "value" as SSJS variable to check the value of the control.

Comment: I have done that - perhaps my issue #1 wasn't clear. The problem is that it is ONLY called when the user HAS added a file name - the "required" property does not seem to work in this context.... - I have edited my question to include the definition of the fileupload.

Comment: A validator is *only* used if there is a value to validate. Empty value (-> no file), no validation.

Comment: Sven, I understand that. And that is why I have tried to use the "required" attribute (which can be calculated) and the validateRequired validator - but it does not trigger for a fileUpload (works fine for other controls). That is why I have tried to "walk around the hot soup" to find another way to validate the contents (i.e. my #2 issue).

Comment: Probably doesn't help as you're binding to beans but I had the same issue. The only workaround was to check via the xspDoc
if( xspDoc.getAttachmentList("Attachment").isEmpty() ){
     var msg = new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Attachment is Mandatory");
     facesContext.addMessage( "Attachment is Mandatory", msg );
     return false;
 };

Comment: Martin, I have seen mentions of this method. Problem is that I can attach a picture to one row... - and, well, I don't think you can call something like "getAttachmentList" for a bean property ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to add a hidden input field to every row. This field's required property depends on the checkbox and the file upload control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="RTItem" action="editDocument" concurrencyMode="force" />
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:repeat id="repeatFiles" rows="30" var="row" value="#{javascript:['A','B','C','D','E','F'];}">
        <xp:checkBox text="File?" id="checkBoxFile" checkedValue="1" uncheckedValue="0" />
        <xp:fileUpload  id="fileUpload" value="#{document1[row]}" />
        <xp:inputHidden id="inputHiddenFileHelper">
            <xp:this.required>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    var cmpCheck = getComponent( "checkBoxFile" );
                    var cmpFile = getComponent( "fileUpload" );

                    if( cmpCheck.value == "0" )
                        return false;

                    if( cmpFile.getValue() == null )
                        return true;
                }]]>
            </xp:this.required>
        </xp:inputHidden>
        <xp:br />
    </xp:repeat>

    <xp:messages id="messages1" />

    <!-- a button to refresh the page -->
    <xp:button value="Submit" id="buttonRefreshMe">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" immediate="false" save="true"/>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```